# How to create and send a PacketOut?

Tags: java, sdn, mininet, opendaylight

I'm trying to do a latency-monitoring system based on the OpenNetMon idea. What I want to do is to inject a packet to a switch so this node will forward the packet to another switch and this one will send it back to the controller. Finally, the controller will measure the latency.

To distinguish this kind of probe packets to make the measurements I will modify the DSCP field from the IPv4 packet.

What I had in mind is when the Opendaylight Controller receive a PacketIn this one will be copied but the DSCP field modified and then the copied_packet/probe_packet will send it to the data plane.

I can extract the RawPacket, EthernetPacket, IPv4Packet from a PacketChain:

```
    RawPacket rawPacket = null;
    EthernetPacket ethernetPacket = null;
    Ipv4Packet ipv4Packet = null;

    for (PacketChain packetChain : packetReceived.getPacketChain()) {
        if (packetChain.getPacket() instanceof RawPacket) {
            rawPacket = (RawPacket) packetChain.getPacket();
        } else if (packetChain.getPacket() instanceof EthernetPacket) {
            ethernetPacket = (EthernetPacket) packetChain.getPacket();
        } else if (packetChain.getPacket() instanceof Ipv4Packet) {
            ipv4Packet = (Ipv4Packet) packetChain.getPacket();
        }
    }
```

How can I send these packets?

Answer (score 0):

You want something along the lines of the following, using PacketProcessingService:

```
NodeConnectorId egress = TABLE_PORT;
TransmitPacketInput input = new TransmitPacketInputBuilder()
                                .setNode(nodeRef(linkDef.srcNodeId))
                                .setEgress(nodeConnectorRef(linkDef.srcNodeId, egress))
                                .setPayload(STUFF)
                                .build();
packetProcessingService.transmitPacket(input);
```

With the following utilities:

```
// reserved ports
public final static NodeConnectorId INGRESS_PORT = new NodeConnectorId("0xfffffff8");
public final static NodeConnectorId TABLE_PORT = new NodeConnectorId("0xfffffff9");
public final static NodeConnectorId NORMAL_PORT = new NodeConnectorId("0xfffffffa"); // optional functionality
public final static NodeConnectorId FLOOD_PORT = new NodeConnectorId("0xfffffffb"); // optional functionality
public final static NodeConnectorId ALL_PORT = new NodeConnectorId("0xfffffffc");
public final static NodeConnectorId CONTROLLER_PORT = new NodeConnectorId("0xfffffffd");
public final static NodeConnectorId LOCAL_PORT = new NodeConnectorId("0xfffffffe");
public final static NodeConnectorId ANY_PORT = new NodeConnectorId("0xffffffff");

public static final InstanceIdentifier<Nodes> NODES_IID = InstanceIdentifier.builder(Nodes.class).build();

public static InstanceIdentifier<Node> nodeIId(NodeId nodeId) {
    return NODES_IID.child(Node.class, new NodeKey(nodeId));
}

public static NodeRef nodeRef(NodeId nodeId) {
    return new NodeRef(nodeIId(nodeId));
}

public static InstanceIdentifier<NodeConnector> nodeConnectorIId(NodeId nodeId, NodeConnectorId ncId) {
    return NODES_IID.child(Node.class, new NodeKey(nodeId)).child(NodeConnector.class, new NodeConnectorKey(ncId));
}

public static NodeConnectorRef nodeConnectorRef(NodeId nodeId, NodeConnectorId ncId) {
    return new NodeConnectorRef(nodeConnectorIId(nodeId, ncId));
}
```

Additionally, you can also set Ingress, which is the port where the packet 'is coming from', used by the in-port matchers.